# Can you desolder and upgrade RAM in Pi boards?

Tags: ram, soc, ddr3

Friendly Electronics has come out with a great small compact but very powerful board. It is called the Nano Pi fire 3. It has 8 cores which is great for programers like myself who want to utilize the cores for clusters and multiprocessing AI machines. However, it only has 1 GB of ram. Therefore, one of the processes I am trying to run can easily take up the ram of the entire board. It is fairly easy and straight forward to attach a cheap memory stick compatible with the board to allow for more swap space. This would be done so that the program can continue to run and not cause the board to entirely run out of memory. However, swap space is slow. Especially because the Nano Pi only allows for a USB 2.0, there is no real fast way to utilize the swap space. Unless I am wrong, then please correct and teach me how I would use the swap space in a faster manner. Now, assuming I am correct, the only way to truly speed up the board would be to actually give it a better physical RAM card. On a Raspberry Pi this is impossible/if you don't REALLY know what you are doing dumb. The reason I say this is because the Raspberry Pi places their RAM cards directly on top of the CPU's. I am not going to post the schematics of the Raspberry Pi, but you are welcome to look them up and fact check me. However, the Nano Pi and other boards from Friendly Electronics don't do this.

(here is the layout of the Nano Pi Fire 3):

[image: NanoPi Fire 3 Layout]

This image is from http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_Fire3

As you can see, the board has 1 GB of DDR3 RAM. It is easy and fairly inexpensive to buy a 16 GB chip of DDR3 RAM. Which is a very viable solution for myself and probably many people trying to get around their issues with slow boards. Is it possible to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: 1.) I don't see that RAM is placed on top of the CPU, I won't look into schematics because I am pretty sure that there is no notation to place RAM chip over CPU. 2.) Installing a 16GB RAM won't solve your problem, since the CPU probably can't address such space - never seen a Rpi board with 16GB. 3.) Why you post pictures of different board and you asking abaot Rpi?

Comment: Is it possible, yes. Practical, no. DDR3 chips look to be a BGA style package, so look up rework tutorials for those and see if it looks like something you want to attempt.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9qC7x5QHIo

Comment: @MarkoBuršič On the older RPis, the RAM is mounted directly on top of the core (PoP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_on_package).

Comment: Possible yes if you have the right equipment (microscope, hot air), the experience to use that equipment and not screw anything up, replacement parts. Also, you have to be sure that the board can even support the new memory otherwise the upgrade would not work. My advise: get a board with more RAM out of the box. It's not worth the risk and hassle to upgrade the RAM.

Comment: POP was used with version 1 of Raspberry Pi later versions use separate ram. other flavours of Pi arwe different to Raspberry pi.

Comment: "Great for programmers … for clusters and AI… Only has 1 GB of RAM… need to add RAM": No, this is **not** great for your application. In fact, it seems to be a total mismatch. Get something different that supports as much RAM as you need. And: An octacore ARM Cortex-A53 isn't really that great a processor. Sure, it has 8 cores. 8 slow cores from 2012 that do roughly one third the computation per MHz of a modern A72 (which are avalaible with twice the MHz, too) with a slow memory interface. **Nothing** about this says "this a good choice for AI applications in 2020".

Comment: "Cluster": Are you serious? You want to put multiple of these into a cluster so that you get the computing performance of a single modern laptop? But none of the interface bandwidth, because, big news: a gigabit ethernet interface (**especially** with the RTL8211E) makes for pretty disappointing distributed compute performance if you have to exchange data once in a while.

Comment: I agree with Marcus - if you want more CPU power, you want something like an NVIDIA Jetson. Or a micro-ITX PC.

Comment: Or, honestly, just a normal µATX PC brick, with a modern AMD multicore CPU and a dedicated GPU. People act as if these ARMs are more power efficient or compact than x86 and classical GPUs for number crunching: they're not. They're just way, way weaker.

Comment: [The data sheet](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/images/8/8b/SEC_S5P6818X_Users_Manual_preliminary_Ver_0.00.pdf) says the S5P6818 supports a maximum of 2GB (1.4.7).